# The element type 'TextSpan' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add TextSpan inside Row but it is throwing the error `The element type 'TextSpan' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.`

`TextSpan(children: [TextSpan(text: 'Some Text')]);`

Answer (score 2):

You to wrap TextSpan inside RichText

```
 RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        children: [
            TextSpan(text: 'Some Text'),
          ],
        ),
    )
```